# How to come out from a not responding or continuously running process 'proc.waitFor()' in groovy

Tags: linux, groovy

I am trying to ping a IP address using a groovy script as below

```
def proc = 'ping -c 1 localhost'.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println "${proc.exitValue()}"=='0' ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK'
```

The code works fine and prints output as OK on a linux machine.
But when the same block of code is executed on a windows, the call 'proc.waitFor()' doesn't respond or goes into a infinite waiting period. As '-c 1' is not a valid option in windows.

But if I use the ping without option '-c'

```
def proc = 'ping localhost'.execute()
```

The above code works fine on windows, since it pings only 4 times and exits. But not on linux it pings continuously until a interrupt and it never reaches the proc.waitFor() line. 
Is there a way to come out of the not responding 'proc.waitFor()' call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [try](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#waitForOrKill%28long%29):

```
proc.waitForOrKill( 10000 ) // 10 seconds
```

instead of

```
proc.waitFor()
```

Comment: I was editing my post with proc.waitForOrKill(), you were faster :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ping -n 1 localhost` in windows. With it you are achieving the same as `ping -c 1 localhost` in linux.

If you are looking for a "groovy solution", see tim_yates's answer.